# GWT Incubator PagingScrollTable compile error

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement this example: http://zenoconsulting.wikidot.com/blog:17 in my gwt app but when i try to compile the project i have this error :

```
 Compiling module com.myapp.security.GwtSpringSecurityProject
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 2 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/C:/_work/Eclipse/MyApp/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/AbstractScrollTable.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.AbstractScrollTable.Impl'
         Rebinding com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.AbstractScrollTable.Impl
            Could not find an exact match rule. Using 'closest' rule <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.AbstractScrollTable.ImplIE6'/> based on fall back values. You may need to implement a specific binding in case the fall back behavior does not replace the missing binding
   Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/C:/_work/Eclipse/MyApp/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-incubator-20101117-r1766.jar!/com/google/gwt/gen2/table/client/FixedWidthTableImpl.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.FixedWidthTableImpl.Impl'
         Rebinding com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.FixedWidthTableImpl.Impl
            Could not find an exact match rule. Using 'closest' rule <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.gen2.table.client.FixedWidthTableImpl.ImplIE8'/> based on fall back values. You may need to implement a specific binding in case the fall back behavior does not replace the missing binding
   [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.internalGet(TypeMap.java:242)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:138)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.processExpression(GenerateJavaAST.java:1144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.dispatch(GenerateJavaAST.java:577)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.dispProcessExpression(GenerateJavaAST.java:603)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.processStatement(GenerateJavaAST.java:1771)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.dispatch(GenerateJavaAST.java:577)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.dispProcessStatement(GenerateJavaAST.java:638)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.processStatements(GenerateJavaAST.java:1846)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.processMethod(GenerateJavaAST.java:1513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST$JavaASTGenerationVisitor.processType(GenerateJavaAST.java:501)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaAST.exec(GenerateJavaAST.java:2958)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:608)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
      [ERROR] <no source info>: public abstract class java.text.DateFormat
    extends java.text.Format
/*   fields   */
protected [unresolved] Unresolved type java.util.Calendar calendar
protected [unresolved] Unresolved type java.text.NumberFormat numberFormat
public static final [unresolved] int ERA_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int YEAR_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int MONTH_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int DATE_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int HOUR_OF_DAY1_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int HOUR_OF_DAY0_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int MINUTE_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int SECOND_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int MILLISECOND_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int DAY_OF_WEEK_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int DAY_OF_YEAR_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int WEEK_OF_YEAR_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int WEEK_OF_MONTH_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int AM_PM_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int HOUR1_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int HOUR0_FIELD
public static final [unresolved] int TIMEZONE_FIELD
private static final [unresolved] long serialVersionUID
public static final [unresolved] int FULL
public static final [unresolved] int LONG
public static final [unresolved] int MEDIUM
public static final [unresolved] int SHORT
public static final [unresolved] int DEFAULT
/*   methods   */
[unresolved] protected void <init>() 
[unresolved] public java.lang.Object clone() 
[unresolved] public boolean equals(java.lang.Object) 
public final java.lang.String format(java.util.Date) 
public final java.lang.StringBuffer format(java.lang.Object, java.lang.StringBuffer, java.text.FieldPosition) 
public abstract java.lang.StringBuffer format(java.util.Date, java.lang.StringBuffer, java.text.FieldPosition) 
[unresolved] private static java.text.DateFormat get(int, int, int, Unresolved type java.util.Locale) 
[unresolved] public static Unresolved type java.util.Locale[] getAvailableLocales() 
[unresolved] public Unresolved type java.util.Calendar getCalendar() 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateInstance() 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateInstance(int) 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateInstance(int, Unresolved type java.util.Locale) 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateTimeInstance() 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateTimeInstance(int, int) 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getDateTimeInstance(int, int, Unresolved type java.util.Locale) 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getInstance() 
[unresolved] public Unresolved type java.text.NumberFormat getNumberFormat() 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getTimeInstance() 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getTimeInstance(int) 
[unresolved] public static final java.text.DateFormat getTimeInstance(int, Unresolved type java.util.Locale) 
[unresolved] public Unresolved type java.util.TimeZone getTimeZone() 
[unresolved] public int hashCode() 
[unresolved] public boolean isLenient() 
[unresolved] public java.util.Date parse(java.lang.String) throws java.text.ParseException
[unresolved] public abstract java.util.Date parse(java.lang.String, Unresolved type java.text.ParsePosition) 
[unresolved] public java.lang.Object parseObject(java.lang.String, Unresolved type java.text.ParsePosition) 
[unresolved] public void setCalendar(Unresolved type java.util.Calendar) 
[unresolved] public void setLenient(boolean) 
[unresolved] public void setNumberFormat(Unresolved type java.text.NumberFormat) 
[unresolved] public void setTimeZone(Unresolved type java.util.TimeZone) 
/*   members   */
Unresolved type java.text.DateFormat$DateFormatGetter
Unresolved type java.text.DateFormat$Field



         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
      [ERROR] at PsTable.java(351): new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(rowValue.getDate())
         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend
      [ERROR] at PsTable.java(351): return new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(rowValue.getDate());
         org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReturnStatement
      [ERROR] at PsTable.java(350): public String getCellValue(Message rowValue);

         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
      [ERROR] at PsTable.java(348): final class PsTable$DateColumnDefinition extends AbstractColumnDefinition 
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JClassType
```

i have simple added the class of this example in my app and i create a new PsTable in my gwt client class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT Incubator's latest release is only compatible with GWT 2.1, and you're apparently using GWT 2.3 or later (the `Could not find an exact match rule. Using 'closest' rule…` was added in 2.3 to support IE9). Add to that that GWT 2.2 breaks binary compatibility of generators (they have to be recompiled against GWT 2.2 or later) and you have a good reason for a failure.

From the GWT Incubator homepage, you should be able to replace `PaagingScrollTable` uses with GWT 2.4's `DataGrid`. It's admittedly a much different approach (cells vs. widgets) but it's the way to go nowadays: GWT Incubator is deprecated (for good reasons) and you really shouldn't use it, move away from it if your project used it, and absolutely **do not** start using it in new projects.

---

BTW, the article you link to is **3 years old**. You can't expect anything good from such ancient code snippets.